# How do I merge two different repositories?

Tags: git, git-merge

I have two repositories, one in Bitbucket and the other in Github.

What I want to do is: merge Bitbucket's repository into Github repository while keeping the commit history of Bitbucket's repository. After merging, Github's repo should have its own commit history alongside Bitbucket's repository commit history. I would like to avoid creating a new repository in Github.

How do I do the above using git?

Comment: Does it help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories

Comment: Add the other `git remote`, `git fetch` the repo and use `git merge` for the branches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

- Clone GitHub repository

  ```
  git clone <github-repo-url>
  ```
- Add Bitbucket repository as remote in the cloned repository

  ```
  git remote add <some-remote-name> <bitbucket-repo-url>
  ```
- Merge the new remote branch with option `--allow-unrelated-histories`

  ```
  git fetch <some-remote-name>
  git merge --allow-unrelated-histories <remote-name>/<branch-name>
  ```
- Push to GitHub remote with `--force` option

  ```
  git push --force <github-remote-name>
  ```

Note that the merge operations might lead to merge conflicts. You can have a look at this [How do you merge two Git repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1425892/10155936) for more options.

Comment: I see, this works too if I want to merge them both in the opposite direction (i.e. assimilating Github repo to Bitbucket repo), right?

Comment: @Richard, yes it should, a bit of caution with the `force` option though

Comment: Thank you, I will try the above when I have access to both repos and update you.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at git mirror here https://help.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/duplicating-a-repository#mirroring-a-repository-in-another-location

It will allow you to automatically pull changes to github when you push to bitbucket.